# Form onChange event using hooks doesn't update variable

Tags: html, reactjs

When i console.log(event.target.data) it is undefined. It does kind of update as it console logs any key.

```
  const [oras,setOras]=useState(null);

  function getData(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOras(event.target.data);
    console.log(event.target.data);
  }
      
   <FormControl aria-label="First name" placeholder="Search" onChange={getData}/>
```

Comment: Pass event in onChange prop like this : onChange={(e)=>getData(e)}

Answer (score 0):

change the `onChange` prop as follows:

```
<FormControl aria-label="First name" placeholder="Search" onChange={event => {getData(event)}/>
```

and the `getData` function as:

```
function getData(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOras(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
```

if `FormControl` is a jsx `input`, then to access the input values with `onChange={event => {getData(event)}` you have to use `event.target.value` within the `getData` function (as seen above), not `event.target.data` (the way you wrote it).